# reading and using the user input data in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tableau-api

I am following https://tableau.github.io/webdataconnector/docs/wdc_multi_table_tutorial I want to get the certain parameters from user and create a url accordingly. this is my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>USGS Earthquake Feed</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store" />
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://connectors.tableau.com/libs/tableauwdc-2.3.latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    (function () {
        // Create the connector object
        var myConnector = tableau.makeConnector();
        myConnector.getSchema = function (schemaCallback) {
            var cols = [{
                id: "MONTH",
                dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.string
            }, {
                id: "METRICKEY",
                alias: "METRICKEY",
                dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.string
            }, {
                id: "NUMERATOR",
                alias: "NUMERATOR",
                dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.float
            }, {
                id: "DENOMINATOR",
                dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.float
            }];

            var tableSchema = {
                id: "feed",
                alias: "Feed",
                columns: cols
            };

            schemaCallback([tableSchema]);
        };

        myConnector.getData = function (table, doneCallback) {
            var filters = tableau.filters;
            console.log("filters");
            console.log(tableau.filters);
            var projections = tableau.projections;
            var apicallUrl = 'test/?name=nb&filters=' + filters + '&projections=' + projections;
            console.log(apicallUrl);
            $.getJSON(apicallUrl, function (resp) {
                var feat = resp.DATA,
                tableData = [];
                // Iterate over the JSON object
                for (var i = 0, len = feat.length; i < len; i++) {
                    tableData.push({
                        "MONTH": feat[i].MONTH,
                        "METRICKEY": feat[i].METRICKEY,
                        "NUMERATOR": feat[i].NUMERATOR,
                        "DENOMINATOR": feat[i].DENOMINATOR
                    });
                }
                table.appendRows(tableData);
                doneCallback();
            });
        };
        tableau.registerConnector(myConnector);
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#submitButton").click(function () {
                var filters = $('#filters').val().trim();
                var projections = $('#projections').val().trim();
                tableau.filters = JSON.stringify(filters);
                tableau.projections = projections;
                tableau.submit();
            });
        });
    })();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container container-table">
        <div class="row vertical-center-row">
            <div class="text-center col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <h2>Get Earthquake Data for a Time Range</h2>
                <form>
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <label for="start-date-one" class="text-center">filters</label>
                        <span>&mdash;</span>
                        <label for="end-date-one">projections</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filters" value="">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="projections" value="">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <button type="button" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-success" style="margin: 10px;">Get Earthquake Data!</button>
                <div id="errorMsg"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get the user data tableau.filters and tableau.projections parameters , but when I try to read them in get dat function the values are coming as undefined. any idea why is this happening ?

Is there any generic way to get user data and use it in some other function in jquery , which I can use here ?

projections and filters are the tex boxes whose value I am reading them in my code in $(document).ready. when I print tableau.filters and tableau.projection value in this function I get the values but when I print these values in getdata() it comes as undefined.

thanks

Comment: I see no reference to projections inside the tutorial you're mentioning. Try `console.log(tableau) ;` or `console.log(tableau.projections);` Investigate the parameter which you added to the `var apicallUrl` that you created to obtain more information.

Comment: @mcv we I print tableau.filters and tableau.projections $(document).ready I get the values but when I print them in getdata(), they comes as undefined.

Comment: Your code is really hard (for me) to read because there's a gap in between every line. I have to scroll a lot. Just something to think about.

Comment: in get data are you sure it's not the variable `table`?!

Comment: @mcv sorry I didn't get you

Comment: I would retrace your steps in the tutorial to see where you went wrong... I can't find any reference to `projections` in the link you provided.

Comment: @mcv ya projection is not in the tutorial it is some thing which I am taking as a user input from the form.

Comment: well why not access the information as you already have gotten it? Use javascript or jQuery inside your getData. I thought getData was to get information from a external url source.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution
It was a silly issue 
we have to write data to connectionData or connectionName parameter of tableau object.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#submitButton").click(function() {
              var urlObject = {
                  filters: $("#filters").val().trim(),
                  projections: $("#projections").val().trim(),
              };
                    tableau.connectionData = JSON.stringify(urlObject);
                    tableau.submit();

            });
        });
```